# Any way to prevent AUTOINCREASE on failed 'INSERT OR IGNORE'?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, auto-increment

Summary of the issue: With MySQL and SQLite, a failed `INSERT OR IGNORE` on a table with AUTOINCREMENT still **increases the autoincremented value**. This has been discussed here: [INSERT IGNORE increases auto increment counter even no record is added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319003/insert-ignore-increases-auto-increment-counter-even-no-record-is-added)

My issue: a table with 99% failed inserts ends up with huge index numbers, for example record 1500 has the index 165200.

This is impractical, so I am looking for a way to counter this behaviour.

Since `INSERT OR IGNORE` is supposedly the same as `INSERT ON CONFLICT IGNORE`, I have thought of using `INSERT ON CONFLICT FAIL` or `INSERT ON CONFLICT ABORT`.

My problem is that I am inserting from a `SELECT` this way:

`INSERT OR IGNORE INTO t1 (x,y,z,) SELECT * FROM t2`

This syntax does not accept `ON CONFLICT FAIL`. **Neither** of those two work:

`INSERT ON CONFLICT FAIL INTO t1 (x,y,z,) SELECT * FROM t2`

`INSERT  INTO t1 (x,y,z,) SELECT * FROM t2 ON CONFLICT FAIL`

Any thoughts or hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `on conflict` is only for sqlite, and is used when you define the constraint (e.g. `... primary key on conflict abort ...`). `abort` will not insert any rows if one of the rows fails. `fail` is even stranger: if you try to insert 5 rows and the 3rd row fails because of keys, it will insert the first 2 rows and stops then. So in short: don't use it. Both versions are NOT the same as `ignore` (at least for more than one row).

There is basically just one way to prevent the autoincrement when you insert multiple rows: don't insert rows that are already in the table.

The usual way to do that is to check if the row exists for yourself instead of the "lazy" `on duplicate key`/`ignore`. E.g. to check for duplicate values in a column `y`:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (x,y,z) 
SELECT * FROM t2 main
where not exists (
    select * from t1 test
    where main.y = test.y);
```

Yes, I know, it will make your code longer. You will unfortunatly have to live with that.